# Como colocar um <p> na mesma linha que o <hr>

Tags: html, css

É possivel colocar o elemento `<hr>` à frente de um elemento `<p>`?

```css
 hr{
   border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p>Colocar a tag <b>hr</b> em frente do <b>p</b> </p><hr>
```

Já tentei utilizar `display:inline` em `<p>` e em `<hr>`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia descrever qual seria o resultado esperado? Se possível, adicione uma imagem ilustrando o que precisa. Aliás, no título há duas vezes a tag `<hr>`.

Comment: @woss coloquei, obrigado

Comment: Amadeu, o que deve acontecer se o `<p>` possuir mais de uma linha?

Comment: @Woss neste caso vai ser algo fixo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vou deixar um exemplo que vai funcionar para todos os casos, com qualquer tamanho de frase (quantas palavras quiser), ou com qualquer `font-size`, ou mesmo em um `<h1>` ou `<p>`

Repare que eu coloque o `p` e o `hr` dentro de um `container` com `display:flex`, isso vai deixar os elementos lado a lado na horizontal, depois eu coloquei `flex:1` no `hr`, isso vai fazer ele crescer e ocupar apenas o espaço restante da largura do `container`.

```css
.meu-hr {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.meu-hr hr {
  flex:1;
  border-color: red;
  margin-left: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="meu-hr">
  <p>123</p><hr>
</div>

<div class="meu-hr">
  <h1>123456</h1><hr>
</div>

<div class="meu-hr">
  <p style="font-size:40px">123456789</p><hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Eu usaria uma div container com flexbox e aplicaria `flex: 1` no `hr` para ele ocupar a largura restante da div onde não está o texto. E um `margin-left` para dar um espaçamento. E em vez de borda, usaria `height: 1px` e o vermelho de cor de fundo. Precisa também retirar as bordas padrão do `hr`, para que ele fique como se fosse uma linha vermelha de 1 pixel de altura.

```css
.paragrafo{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}

.paragrafo hr{
   background: red;
   flex: 1;
   margin-left: 10px;
   height: 1px;
   border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="paragrafo">
   <p>Colocar a tag <b>hr</b> em frente do <b>p</b></p><hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
 hr{
   margin-top:-25px;
   margin-left:213px;
   border-top: 1px solid red;
   }
```

```html
<p>Colocar a tag <b>hr</b> em frente do <b>p</b> </p><hr>
```

Comment: qual o problema na resposta?

Comment: Para mim está certo é isso mesmo, mas seria interessante saber o porque a quem negativou

Comment: Bom, nem fui em que negativei, mas se ele trocar o `<p>` por `<h1>`, ou simplesmente trocar o tamanho da fonte. Ou mesmo **se colocar uma palavra a mais  na frase a sua resposta já não serve mais**. Ela é praticamente insustentável, pois usa valares fixos, e qq alteração mesmo que um `font-size` já vai fazer ela deixar de funcionar... O usuário  vai ter que fazer uma classe CSS para cada frase diferente que for usar.  Pode até resolver o problema do autor, mas está longe de ser um forma indicada

Comment: Qual seria a forma mais correcta?

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes: Eu dei um up vote pois acredito que soluções de design estático também sejam válidas só não sejam as mais flexíveis em tempos de multi dispositivos. Mas a forma não mais correta, mas mais adequada seria manipular o layout de renderização com a propriedade CSS [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/display)